# Create NotifyIcon and handle click event with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create NotifyIcon with Powershell and then handle the $notifyIcon.BallonTipClicked event.

With the following code the NotifyIcon is displayed but im unable to assign the BallonTipClicked event an event handler.

After running the code im getting the following error:
The property "BallonTipClicked" for this Object was not found. Make sure that the property is available and can be defined.

```
#import .net component
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# initiallize notification
$notification = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
$notification.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
$notification.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info
$notification.BalloonTipTitle = "Updates Available"
$notification.BalloonTipText = "Click to run updates"

$notification.Visible = $true
$notification.ShowBalloonTip(3000)

# assign an event handler for the event
$notification.BalloonTipClicked += [System.EventHandler](BalloonTip_Clicked)


# function that should be triggered when the balloontip is clicked
function BalloonTip_Clicked {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.Object]
        $Sender,
        [Parameter()]
        [System.EventArgs]
        $e
    )
    $notification.Dispose()
}
```

I have been looking for a solution but i cant find any examples in powershell. I hope someone can give me a hint.
Here are some C# [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=net-5.0) of event handling from microsoft but i couldnt implement them in powershell.

My powershell version is:  5.1.18362.1171
dotnet version is: 5.0.102

Comment: I have found this post that helped me handle click events. And much much more. Very helpfull!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649456/powershell-notifyicon-context-menu

@ArcSet thank you!

Comment: Would be nice if someone could show how its done in a different way, using the .NET object (EventHandler). if possible

Comment: There is documentation regarding how to use C# in PowerShell scripts, and many examples on SO, all over the web and on Youtube. Just search for that. Why not just use the BurntToast module?

Comment: @postanote...not in all situations third party modules could be used, for any reason.