# How can I get the selected item in a Notify Icon context menu within Powershell?

Tags: powershell, winforms, event-handling, contextmenu

My code is below. I'd like to get the item/text selected from the notify icon context menu and also trigger an event from it. I can't figure out how to obtain which menu item was clicked and am not able to trigger any events. I have read and reread the stackoverflow link in the Powershell comment and have not had success. Thanks.

As a note, you'll need to specify an ico file twice at the top to see the icon in the system tray.

```
<#
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649456/powershell-notifyicon-context-menu   
#>

cls;

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
 
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$notifyIcon= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;
$iconOK = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);
$iconWarn = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);
 
$menuItem1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem;
$menuItem1.Text = "Menu Item 1";
$menuItem1.Name = "MenuItem1";
$menuItem1.Tag = "MenuItem1";

$menuItem2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem;
$menuItem2.Text = "Menu Item 2";
$menuItem2.Name = "MenuItem2";
$menuItem2.Tag = "MenuItem2";

$menuItem3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem;
$menuItem3.Text = "Menu Item 3";
$menuItem3.Name = "MenuItem3";
$menuItem3.Tag = "MenuItem3";

$contextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu;
$contextMenu.Name = "Context menu name";
$contextMenu.Tag = "Context menu tag";
$contextMenu.MenuItems.Add($menuItem1) | Out-Null;
$contextMenu.MenuItems.Add($menuItem2) | Out-Null;
$contextMenu.MenuItems.Add($menuItem3) | Out-Null;
 
$notifyIcon.Icon =  $iconOK;
$notifyIcon.Visible = $True;

$menuItem1.add_Click
({
    Write-Host "menuItem1.add_Click";
})

$menuItem2.add_Click
({
    Write-Host "menuItem2.add_Click";
})

$menuItem3.add_Click
({
    Write-Host "menuItem3.add_Click";
})

$contextMenu.add_Click
({
    Write-Host "contextMenu.add_Click";
})

$notifyIcon.ContextMenu = $contextMenu;
$global:notifyIconContextMenu = $notifyIcon.ContextMenu.PSObject.Copy();
$notifyIconContextMenuMenuItems = $notifyIconContextMenu.MenuItems;

$notifyIcon.Add_Click({ 

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderNotifyIconAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsNotifyIconAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    $global:menuItemTest = $senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu;   
    $global:selectedContextItem = ([System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu]$senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu)#.CommandParameter as User;
    
    if ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Left) 
    {
        #$form1.WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"  
        $form1.Show();
        $form1.Activate();
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click left click";
    }
    elseif ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right) 
    {
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click right click";
    }       
})

$form1.add_Closing({

    $notifyIcon.Dispose();
    Write-Host "form.add_Closing completed";
    return;
 });

[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working example, the only thing needed will be to provide a file path to the icon files, otherwise this will allow someone to paste and modify to suit their own needs. The issue was that I should have been using a `contextmenustrip` and `toolstripitem`, rather than a contextmenu and menuitem.

```
cls;

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
 
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$notifyIcon= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;
$iconOK = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);
$iconWarn = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);


$notifyIcon.Icon =  $iconOK;
$notifyIcon.Visible = $True;





$toolStripItemOne = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'File'
$toolStripItemOne.add_Click({   

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemOneAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemOneAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
        
    Write-Host "toolStripItemOne.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemOneAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemTwo = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Edit'
$subMenuItemOne = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
$subMenuItemOne.Text = "Copy";
$subMenuItemOne.add_Click({
    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderSubMenuItemOneAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsSubMenuItemOneAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "subMenuItemOne.add_Click - " $senderSubMenuItemOneAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemTwo.DropDownItems.Add($subMenuItemOne) | Out-Null;


$subMenuItemTwo = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
$subMenuItemTwo.Text = "Paste";
$subMenuItemTwo.add_Click({
    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderSubMenuItemTwoAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsSubMenuItemTwoAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "subMenuItemTwo.add_Click - " $senderSubMenuItemTwoAddClick.Text;
});
$toolStripItemTwo.DropDownItems.Add($subMenuItemTwo) | Out-Null;

$toolStripItemTwo.add_Click({   

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemTwoAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemTwoAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemTwo.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemTwoAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemThree = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Save'
$toolStripItemThree.add_Click({ 

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemThreeAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemThreeAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemThree.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemThreeAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemFour = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Close'
$toolStripItemFour.add_Click({  

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemFourAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemFourAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemFour.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemFourAddClick.Text;
    
    $form1.Close();
});


$contextMenuStrip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip;
$contextMenuStrip.Name = "Context menu strip name";
$contextMenuStrip.Tag = "Context menu strip tag";
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemOne);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemTwo);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemThree);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemFour);
$contextMenuStrip.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(153, 70);


$notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenuStrip;
$global:notifyIconContextMenuStrip = $notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.PSObject.Copy();
$notifyIconContextMenuMenuItems = $notifyIconContextMenu.MenuItems;

$notifyIcon.Add_Click({ 

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderNotifyIconAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsNotifyIconAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    $global:menuItemTest = $senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu;   
    $global:selectedContextItem = ([System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu]$senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu);
    
    if ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Left) 
    {
        $form1.Show();
        $form1.Activate();
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click left click";
    }
    elseif ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right) 
    {
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click right click";
    }       
})

$form1.add_Closing({

    $notifyIcon.Dispose();
    Write-Host "form.add_Closing completed";
    return;
 });

[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form1);
```

and here is how to display a label as the icon, which can be dynamically updated within the code

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
 
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$notifyIcon= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;
$iconOK = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);
$iconWarn = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon([you'll need to find an icon for this using get-childitem -Recurse -Filter "*.ico" -File -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);

$memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream;
$idleTimeBitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap(40, 14);
$idleTimeFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft San Serif",7,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular);
$idleTimeBrushForegroundColor = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::White;
$idleTimeBrushBackgroundColor = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black;
$idleTimeImageGraphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($idleTimeBitmap);
$idleTimeImageGraphics.FillRectangle($idleTimeBrushBackgroundColor,0,0,$idleTimeBitmap.Width,$idleTimeBitmap.Height) 
$idleTimeImageGraphics.DrawString("00:00:00", $idleTimeFont, $idleTimeBrushForegroundColor, 1, 1);
$idleTimeBitmap.Save($memoryStream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Bmp);

$toolStripItemOne = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'File'
$toolStripItemOne.add_Click({   

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemOneAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemOneAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
        
    Write-Host "toolStripItemOne.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemOneAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemTwo = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Edit'
$subMenuItemOne = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
$subMenuItemOne.Text = "Copy";
$subMenuItemOne.add_Click({
    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderSubMenuItemOneAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsSubMenuItemOneAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "subMenuItemOne.add_Click - " $senderSubMenuItemOneAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemTwo.DropDownItems.Add($subMenuItemOne) | Out-Null;


$subMenuItemTwo = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
$subMenuItemTwo.Text = "Paste";
$subMenuItemTwo.add_Click({
    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderSubMenuItemTwoAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsSubMenuItemTwoAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "subMenuItemTwo.add_Click - " $senderSubMenuItemTwoAddClick.Text;
});
$toolStripItemTwo.DropDownItems.Add($subMenuItemTwo) | Out-Null;

$toolStripItemTwo.add_Click({   

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemTwoAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemTwoAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemTwo.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemTwoAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemThree = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Save'
$toolStripItemThree.add_Click({ 

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemThreeAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemThreeAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemThree.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemThreeAddClick.Text;
});

$toolStripItemFour = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'Close'
$toolStripItemFour.add_Click({  

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderToolStripItemFourAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsToolStripItemFourAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    Write-Host "toolStripItemFour.add_Click - " $senderToolStripItemFourAddClick.Text;
    
    $form1.Close();
});


$memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream;
$idleTimeBitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap(32, 20);
$idleTimeFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft San Serif",12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular);
$idleTimeBrushForegroundColor = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::White;
$idleTimeBrushBackgroundColor = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black;
$idleTimeImageGraphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($idleTimeBitmap);
$idleTimeImageGraphics.FillRectangle($idleTimeBrushBackgroundColor,0,0,$idleTimeBitmap.Width,$idleTimeBitmap.Height) 
$idleTimeImageGraphics.DrawString("14", $idleTimeFont, $idleTimeBrushForegroundColor, 1, 1);
$idleTimeBitmap.Save($memoryStream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Bmp);
$idleTimeIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle($idleTimeBitmap.GetHicon());

$contextMenuStrip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip;
$contextMenuStrip.Name = "Context menu strip name";
$contextMenuStrip.Tag = "Context menu strip tag";
$contextMenuStripLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label;
$contextMenuStripLabel.Text = "contextMenuStripLabel";
$toolStripItemLabel = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
$toolStripControlHost = New-Object Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost($contextMenuStripLabel);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.Insert(0, $toolStripControlHost);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.Add($toolStripControlHost) | Out-Null;
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemOne);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemTwo);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemThree);
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange($toolStripItemFour);
$contextMenuStrip.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(153, 70);
#$notifyIcon.Icon =  $iconOK;
$notifyIcon.Visible = $True;
$notifyIcon.Icon = $idleTimeIcon;

$notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenuStrip;
$global:notifyIconContextMenuStrip = $notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.PSObject.Copy();
$notifyIconContextMenuMenuItems = $notifyIconContextMenu.MenuItems;

$notifyIcon.Add_Click({ 

    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.EventArgs] $e
        )
        
    $global:senderNotifyIconAddClick = $sender.PSObject.Copy();
    $global:eventArgsNotifyIconAddClick = $e.PSObject.Copy();
    
    $global:menuItemTest = $senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu;   
    $global:selectedContextItem = ([System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu]$senderNotifyIconAddClick.ContextMenu);
    
    if ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Left) 
    {
        $form1.Show();
        $form1.Activate();
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click left click";
    }
    elseif ($_.Button -eq [Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right) 
    {
        Write-Host "$notifyIcon.Add_Click right click";
    }       
})

$form1.add_Closing({

    $notifyIcon.Dispose();
    Write-Host "form.add_Closing completed";
    return;
 });

[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form1);
```