# How to exit a powershell script that runs in the systray?

Tags: powershell, winforms, click, exit, systray

I would like to exit this systray program by clicking with the left mouse on the text "Quit.". When I hover, the mouse shows a rotating blue icon and clicking does nothing. What's the problem with the script?

```
# a systray program, that should be exited (but it doesn't)
# 2023-03-18


$iconPath = "H:\Dropbox\400 - Scriptprogrammierung\Powershell\Taskleiste mit Wochentag\icons\ico\Logo.ico" # icon path
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $iconPath
$tooltip = "This is a text."

# NotifyIcon-object
$notifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$notifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($iconPath)
$notifyIcon.Text = $tooltip

########################
# Here seems to be the problem...
$contextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip
$menuItemExit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$menuItemExit.Text = "Quit."
$contextMenu.Items.Add($menuItemExit)
$notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenu
$menuItemExit.add_Click({ $notifyIcon.Dispose(); exit })
########################

# Show icon in systray
$notifyIcon.Visible = $true

# Loop
while ($true) {
    $notifyIcon.Text = $tooltip
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 # wait 60 seconds
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649456/powershell-notifyicon-context-menu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crucial changes required are:

- Do not call `exit` directly from the `.add_Click()` event-handler script block: It will crash your script.

  - The code below also moves `$notifyIcon.Dispose()` out of this script block and instead moves it into a `finally` block of a `try` statement that wraps the `while` loop, and notifies the loop of the desire to quit via a script-level `$done` variable, which is set via `$script:done = $true` from the event handler (which runs in a *child* scope of the script).
  - This ensures that using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to terminate the script also properly disposes of the icon and removes it from the notification area.
- **In your `while` loop, you must periodically call `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` in order to allow WinForms to process its UI events**. Sleep only a *short* while between these calls, so as to keep the UI responsive - a long sleep would block event processing for the duration of that sleep.

  - An **alternative, blocking way to implement the event loop** is to create an application context ([`ApplicationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext)) and use it in a single, blocking [`[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run#system-windows-forms-application-run(system-windows-forms-applicationcontext)) call - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75899085/45375).

```bash
# Load the WinForms assembly.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Use PowerShell's icon in this example; be sure to use a full path.
$iconPath = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
$tooltip = "This is a text."

# Construct the NotifyIcon object.
$notifyIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
$notifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($iconPath)
$notifyIcon.Text = $tooltip

# Define a script-level variable that indicates whether the
# script should be exited, to be set to $true from the .add_Click() event handler.
$done = $false

$contextMenu = [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip]::new()
$menuItemExit = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem]::new()
$menuItemExit.Text = "Quit."
$null = $contextMenu.Items.Add($menuItemExit)
$notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenu
# Set the script-level $done variable to $true when the menu item is clicked.
$menuItemExit.add_Click({ $script:done = $true })

# Show icon in systray (notification area)
$notifyIcon.Visible = $true

Write-Verbose -Verbose @"
Adding a PowerShell icon to notification area (system tray).
Use the icon's context menu to quit this script, 
or press Ctrl-C in the console window.
"@

# Loop
try {
  while (-not $done) {
      # IMPORTANT: Make WinForms process its events.
      [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
      # Sleep just a little, to keep the UI responsive.
      # Note:
      #   In theory, you could perform other tasks here,
      #   as long as they complete quickly so as to still
      #   allow frequent enough ::DoEvents() calls.
      Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 100
  }
}
finally {
  # Dispose of the notify icon, which also removes it from display.
  $notifyIcon.Dispose()
  Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Exiting.'
}
```

Comment: Now, the script runs as expected. Thank you very much for your professional help.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't exit. Shouldn't there be more disposal code in the finally block? 
`$notifyIcon.Visible = $false` | `$notifyIcon.Dispose()` | `$window.Close()` | `Stop-Process $pid` works for me.

Comment: @fmotion1, I've made the sample self-contained, and it does exit for me - as I would expect it to. `$notifyIcon.Dispose()` implicitly removes the icon from the notification area - no need to make it invisible first. There is no `$window` object in the code - if you do  have a form, you indeed have to close it (and then should `.Dispose()` it) in order to exit. No need for `Stop-Process` if you call the script via the PowerShell CLI (`powershell -File ...`) - exiting the script will also exit the PowerShell process.