# issue with powerhell running minimized as icon tray

Tags: powershell

I have this code to create a very simple hidden process with an icon tray an a context menu. when the function gets activated via contest menu the script starts sending the letter "q" every 5 seconds.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')   | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')          | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('WindowsFormsIntegration') | out-null

$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe") 

# Part - Add the systray menu
    
$Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$Main_Tool_Icon.Text = "WPF Systray tool"
$Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = $icon
$Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $true

$Menu_Exit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$Menu_Exit.Text = "Exit"

$contextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
$Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu = $contextmenu

#by Franco
$Menu_Key = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$Menu_Key.Text = "Invia pressione tasto ogni 5 secondi"

$Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($Menu_Exit)
$Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($Menu_Key)

# When Exit is clicked, close everything and kill the PowerShell process
$Menu_Exit.add_Click({
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $false
    Stop-Process $pid

 })

#send Key "q" every 5 seconds
 $Menu_key.add_Click({
$a = new-object -com "wscript.shell"

    while ($true){

sleep 5 
$a.sendkeys("q")

}
 })

 
# Make PowerShell Disappear
$windowcode = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
$asyncwindow = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $windowcode -name Win32ShowWindowAsync -namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$null = $asyncwindow::ShowWindowAsync((Get-Process -PID $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0) 

# Force garbage collection just to start slightly lower RAM usage.
[System.GC]::Collect()

# Create an application context for it to all run within.
# This helps with responsiveness, especially when clicking Exit.
$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

the problem happens when I want to exit the script with the exit menu context button, it doesn't actually exit  until I click again on the icon tray with the left mouse button.
As soon as I click the icon with the left mouse button the icon disappears and it stops sending the letter "q".
The problem doesn't occur when I exit the scrip wia icon context menu without first activating the sendkeys method via context menu. but if I change the code like this:

`#send Key "q" every 5 seconds`

`$Menu_key.add_Click({`

`$a = new-object -com "wscript.shell"`

`$c = 0`

`while ($c -lt 5){`

`sleep 5`

`$a.sendkeys("q")`

`$c++`

`}`

`})`

it exits, after clicking the same exit button, only after the while cycle ended, is there a way to interupt the cycle before it finishes?

I also don't understand what the following part of the script does:

`$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext`

`[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)`

and

`#Force garbage collection just to start slightly lower RAM usage.`

`[System.GC]::Collect()`

I download the model on gitHub: [Build-PS1-Systray-Tool](https://github.com/damienvanrobaeys/Build-PS1-Systray-Tool)

Thanks for the help

Franco

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't understand what the following part of the script does:

> `[System.GC]::Collect()`

It **forces *synchronous* [garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)**, i.e. the reclaiming of memory occupied by objects that are no longer being referenced by any application.
**Doing so is *not* relevant to your script**, given that there's no obvious reason to do this: there has been *no* build-up of no-longer-referenced objects that may cause memory pressure that therefor needs relieving.

> `$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext`
> `[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)`

This code is **necessary in order for your notification-area (system-tray) icon to process *(WinForms) GUI events***, so that interacting with the associated context menu works as expected.

Specifically, it starts a blocking windows message loop via [`[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run#system-windows-forms-application-run(system-windows-forms-applicationcontext)) that runs until the application-context object stored in `$appContext` ([`[System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext) signals the desire to exit via a call to `.ExitThread()`.

This is analogous to a call to `.ShowDialog()` in the more typical WinForms scenario where a *form* is to be shown modally; in that case, the blocking call ends when the form is *closed*.

---

Unless you explicit create additional threads, your script runs in a single thread, including the script blocks that server as your event delegates.

You mention ending up using **`Start-ThreadJob`** for performing your periodic task, which is actually the ***preferable* solution**, as it enables you to perform even long-running tasks in parallel, without interfering with the responsiveness of your UI.

Indeed it is the single-threaded nature of your original script that caused the problem: your `sleep 5` (`Start-Sleep -Seconds 5`) call in the `$Menu_key.add_Click()` event handler *blocked* UI event processing, causing the symptoms you saw.

There are ways to avoid this, but creating a separate thread gives you more flexibility.
That said, in your particular case - running a quick action every N seconds - using a WinForms timer object may be the simplest solution.

---

The following self-contained **sample code** demonstrates **three approaches to running an action periodically in the context of a WinForms application**:

- Use of a thread job with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) to run the action in a separate thread.
- Use of a WinForms timer object ([`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer)) to automatically invoke a script block every N seconds.
- Use of a nested, manual event-processing loop via [`System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents) that calls in - of necessity short - intervals to process UI events while performing other operations in between.
  Note: This works well in single-form, single-notification-icon scenarios, but should be avoided otherwise.

  - A way to avoid a *nested* `DoEvents()` loop is to forgo use of an application context and [`[Application]::Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run#system-windows-forms-application-run(system-windows-forms-applicationcontext)) altogether, and instead implement a single `DoEvents()` loop in the main thread - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778669/45375)

Note:

- The code, which builds on yours, is streamlined in several respects, both syntax-wise and through its use of [`System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip) and [`System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem) to replace the obsolete [`System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu) and [`System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menuitem) classes, both of which are no longer available in .NET (Core) 3.1+.
- The PowerShell-window-hiding code is commented out, to keep the session visible, because the periodic actions are simulated with output to the console, via [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose).
- [`ApplicationContext.ExitThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.exitthread) is used to exit the message loop so as to enable an orderly shutdown, as the better alternative to *killing* the current process via [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process)
- See the source-code comments for details.

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Setting up a notification (system-tray) with a context menu, using PowerShell''s icon...'

# Create the context menu.
$contextMenuStrip = [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip]::new()

# Create the notification (systray) icon and attach the context menu to it.
$notifyIcon = 
  [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon] @{
    Text        = "WinForms notification-area utility"
    # Use PowerShell's icon
    Icon        = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path) 
    ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenuStrip
    Visible     = $true
  }

# Add menu items to the context menu.
$contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(@(
    ($menuItemExit = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem] @{ Text = 'Exit' })
    ($menuItemDoPeriodically = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem] @{ Text = 'Do something periodically' })
  ))

# How frequently to take action.
$periodInSeconds = 2

# Set up a WinForms timer that is invoked periodically - to be started later.
$timer = [System.Windows.Forms.Timer] @{ InterVal = $periodInSeconds * 1000 }
$timer.Add_Tick({
  # Sample action: Print a verbose message to the console.
  # See note re need for the action to run quickly below.
  Write-Verbose -vb Tick
})

# Set up the context menu-item event handlers:

$menuItemExit.add_Click({
    # Dispose of the timer and the thread job and set the script-scope variable to signal that exiting has been requested.
    $timer.Dispose()
    if ($script:threadJob) { $threadJob | Remove-Job -Force }
    $script:done = $true
    # Tell the WinForms application context to exit its message loop.
    # This will cause the [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run() call below to return.
    $appContext.ExitThread()
    # Dispose of and thereby implicitly remove the notification icon.
    $notifyIcon.Dispose() 
  })

$menuItemDoPeriodically.add_Click({

    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Starting periodic actions, first invocation in $periodInSeconds seconds..."

    # Best solution, using a thread job.
    # Since it runs in a *separate thread*, there's no concern about blocking the
    # main thread with long-running operations, such as extended sleeps.
    $script:threadJob = Start-ThreadJob {
      while ($true) {
        Start-Sleep $using:periodInSeconds
        # Sample action: print a message to the console.
        # Note: [Console]::WriteLine() writes directly to the display, for demo purposes.
        #       Otherwise, the output from this thread job would have to be collected on
        #       demand with Receive-Job 
        [Console]::WriteLine('Tock')
      }
    }

    # *Single-threaded solutions* that rely on whatever runs periodically
    # to run *quickly enough* so as to not block event processing, which
    # is necessary to keep the notification icon and its context menu responsive.

    # Solution with the previously set up WinForms timer.
    $timer.Start()

    # Alternative: A manual loop, which allows foreground activity while waiting
    # for the next period to elapse.
    # To keep the notification icon and its context menu responsive, 
    # [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() must be called in *short intervals*,
    # i.e. whatever action you perform must run *quickly enough* so as to keep the UI responsive.
    # This effectively makes *this* loop the UI event loop, which works in this simple case,
    # but is generally best avoided.
    # Keep looping until the script-level $done variable is set to $true
    $sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    while (-not $script:done) {
      if ($sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -ge $periodInSeconds) { # Period has elapsed.
        $sw.Reset(); $sw.Start()
        # Sample action: Print a verbose message to the console.
        Write-Verbose -vb Tack
      }
      # Ensure that WinForms GUI events continue to be processed.
      [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
      # Sleep a little to lower CPU usage, but short enough to keep the
      # context menu responsive.
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
  })

# Activate this block to hide the current PowerShell window.
# For this demo, the window is kept visible to see event output.
# # Hide this PowerShell window.
# (Add-Type -PassThru -NameSpace NS$PID -Name CHideMe -MemberDefinition '
#     [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
#     public static void HideMe() { ShowWindow(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, 0 /* SW_HIDE */); }
# ')::HideMe()

# Initialize the script-level variable that signals whether the script should exit.
$done = $false

Write-Verbose -Verbose @'
Starting indefinite event processing for the notification-area icon (look for the PowerShell icon)...
Use its context menu:
 * to start periodic actions
 * to exit - do NOT use Ctrl-C.
'@

# Create an application context for processing WinForms GUI events.
$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext

# Synchronously start a WinForms event loop for the application context.
# This call will block until the Exit context-menu item is invoked.
$null = [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)

# The script will now exit.
# Note: If you run the script from an *interactive* session, the session will live on (see below)
#       In a PowerShell CLI call, the process will terminate.
Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Exiting...'

# # Activate this statement to *unconditionally* terminate the process,
# # even when running interactively.
# $host.SetShouldExit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! @mklemant0  you are a really guru of powershell! I took a couple of day to study your answer. the updated script you rewrote is very precious to me. I don't think there are many people who know powershel that well